# There are two `dhcpcd` files in Debian buster - why is that?

Tags: systemd, raspbian, dhcpcd

I was digging into `dhcpcd` behavior, and I've found something that confuses me: `dhcpcd` vs. `dhcpcd5`.

```
$ which dhcpcd
/sbin/dhcpcd
```

But `dhcpcd` is only a link: `dhcpcd -> /etc/alternatives/dhcpcd`, which in turn points back to: `dhcpcd -> /sbin/dhcpcd5`. So - a `dhcpcd` and a `dhcpcd5` - both in `sbin`.

On my Raspberry Pi `dhcpcd` is apparently invoked at boot time from `/etc/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service.d/wait.conf` using this command: `ExecStart=/usr/lib/dhcpcd5/dhcpcd -q -w`. AFAIK, neither `dhcpcd` nor `dhcpcd5` are called anywhere else in the system.

I guessed there must be a reason for all of this, but after searching I could find no explanation. Why was `dhcpcd` renamed `dhcpcd5`? Also - if it's only called once by `systemd` at boot time, why all the links & alternative/synonym?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all for historical reasons. There used to be a [`dhcpd` package](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/dhcpcd) which integrated with `ifupdown`, running one instance of `dhpcd` per interface.

Version 5 of the project changed behaviour, with a single instance handling all interfaces. To simplify upgrades, it was packaged [as an entirely new package](https://bugs.debian.org/594672); this allowed administrators to have both versions in parallel, and handle the configuration upgrade as they saw fit.

The `dhcpcd` symlink is still used by the init script on non-systemd-managed systems.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. It jibes with the info on [Marples' History page](https://roy.marples.name/projects/dhcpcd/history.html), and there are always legacy issues to be addressed. This "connects the dots" between the name change and handling multiple interfaces in a single instance. Thanks for clearing this up.

Answer (score 1):

This is the "alternatives" system in action.
In this system the conventional name of the program is a symbolic link into `/etc/alternatives/` and the actual program binary is a differently named file somewhere else.

You can see this with other programs that are set up to use the "alternatives" system.  For example: Whilst `/usr/bin/vim` is the conventional name for VIM, the actual program binaries that the "alternatives" system permits switching between are variously `/usr/bin/vim.tiny`, `/usr/bin/vim.nox`, and so forth.

In this particular case, there used to be two alternatives, `/sbin/dhcpcd5` provided by [the `dhcpcd5` package](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/dhcpcd5) and `/sbin/dhcpcd3` provided by [the `dhcpcd` package](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/dhcpcd).
In the post-install maintainer scripts for their packages ([dhcpcd5](https://sources.debian.org/src/dhcpcd5/5.5.6-1+deb7u1/debian/postinst/) [dhcpcd](https://sources.debian.org/src/dhcpcd/1:3.2.3-11+deb7u1/debian/postinst/)) they would each use `update-alternatives` to make the "alternatives" system create the `dhcpd` symbolic link at the conventional name, picking the highest priority underlying binary that is installed.

As M. Kitt noted, the package that provided `dhcpcd3` has been removed.
So this is now an "alternatives" configuration with only one possible alternative.  ☺